# Avoiding a CSS3 box-shadow to be seen while fading in a <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm fading in some `<li>` elements (boxes) when my users click a button. The boxes [used to have PNG backgrounds](http://www.datanordar.se/jobb) and now I'm replacing them with pure CSS. I'm using [Getting clever with CSS3 Shadows](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-getting-clever-with-css3-shadows/), using `li:after`.

The problem with this method is that when I `fadeIn` the boxes they'll naturally have opacity and thus the shadow [will be seen through](http://cl.ly/2T0V2E1K221S1Z3Z222w).

Setting the `box-shadow` on the `<li>` element doesn't create the shadow effect I'm after. I tried creating a  that I append once the fadeIn is complete, and it sorta works but is noticeable.

Any ideas on a better way?

Comment: What shadow effect are you after?

Comment: Here's what it should look like when the fadeIn is completed: http://cl.ly/2M3B2H1e2X3H053g3r0C. And that works, just not *during* the 180ms that the fadeIn is occuring, since the shadow is then seen through (as seen in my first screenshot).

Comment: Great. It's generally a good idea with questions like this to post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that the army of hackers on SO can play with it ;)

Comment: Cool, I'll do that unless someone pops up with an answer. I added a link to the existing site with the PNGs, too.

Comment: Well the obvious answer is to align the psuedoelement better with the parent and fade it as well, however without the code it's hard to judg if it will work and how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could do with by wrapping it all up in a "wrapper" element inside the li element and then fading the li element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/ncBtV/1/embedded/result/

*Only tested it in Chrome dev and Firefox 4*

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class when the animation is completed...

#### CSS

```
li.completed-fade {
   box-shadow: ...
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('li').fadeIn(500, function() { $(this).addClass('completed-fade'); });
```

Comment: I could, but that will still make the shadow appear *after* the fadeIn of the element is completed. That's what I'd like to avoid :-)